# Does ASAN affects symbols definitions and ODR?

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

I have a library (A) which has a class template and some functions which receive as an argument an instance of the class template. I have found that one of the functions is inlining the class constructor and when I compile as a shared library, it doesn't export the class constructor definition. This flag is compile with -O3 and without ASAN.

A

```
template <typename T>
class S {
...
};

S<float> foo(const S<float> s) {
    S<float> out;
    // Does some stuff with s and stores in out
    return out;
}
```

I have another library (B) which links to A. It also uses the class template and the function

B

```
float doSomething() {
    S<float> input;
    S<float> out = foo(input);
}
```

This second library is also compile with -O3, but this time without ASAN.

I have checked the symbols in A and in B, and the S constructor is not in A, so I believe that the constructor is inlined inside `doSomething`. However, the S constructor exists in B.

My question is, does having a library with ASAN and another one without ASAN affects ODR violation?

Comment: ASAN is a red herring. Template instantiations are weak symbols. The final linking gets rid from all but one of each duplicate instantiation.

Comment: My point is that in the A lib the S constructor is not exported, but inlined, so it doesn't even reach the linker. And I fear that when compiling B, the S constructor is defined differently than when compiling B lib.

Comment: "And I fear that when compiling B, the S constructor is defined differently" It's your responsibility to make sure this does not happen. This is no different from any other program that contains more than one TU. Again, it doesn't matter what does or does not get inlined in different libraries, or whether ASAN is used.

Comment: And I am trying to try to address my responsability with this question. I dont know is compiling one TU with ASAN and another without ASAN affects the ODR. I know some sanitizers modify the code internally, or even ASAN can modify code, so I dont know if it can affect ODR

Comment: " I dont know is compiling one TU with ASAN and another without ASAN affects the ODR" Well, all of the standard library and all of your third-party libraries you don't have source to are compiled without ASAN. If it were an issue, ASAN would be simply useless.

Comment: ODR is a requirement on C++ programs, that is, on source code. If your source for the entire program does not contain ODR violations, then there are no ODR violations, and no implementation can change that. (Actually all requirements in the standard are requirements placed on the implementation, but it is easier to  restate them as requirements on programs). You can ask a question "Is it safe to compile some libraries with ASAN and some without and link them together?" and it's a legitimate question (the answer happens to be yes), but it has nothing to do with ODR.

Comment: Thanks. However, AFAIK compiler flags can modify how the compiler sees a header file, in this case containing a template, and compile differently depending on the compilation flags (obvious example would be to compile Eigen with different architectures). That will produce an ODR violation. I wanted to know if that could happen with ASAN, which you have already answered. If you provide a complete answer (not a commet), Ill accept it

Comment: Flags like `-D` simply change the definition of what your TU is. It is no longer a physical file, but a file prepended with some compiler-generated `#define` directives. Other flags may change core properties of the abstract machine (for example `sizeof(wchar_t)`), in this case we are talking about a family of related implementations anf it may or may not be safe to mix and match them. The compiler manual usually warns about such unsafe flags. In any case flags do not produce ODR violations, ODR is a rule about source code, not about compiled code. (The standard does not govern compiled code).

Comment: I will try to write an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

There are compiler options that need to be applied globally, to all translation units of the program, otherwise the resulting binaries cannot be linked together. The ASAN options are not of that nature. (Otherwise ASAN would be unusable in practice).

The address sanitizer does two things:

- at the lonker level, replaces `malloc` and friends with functionally equivalent routines that provide additional  functionality
- at the compiler level, instruments emitted code to use that additional functionality

It doesn't change any ABIs in an incompatible manner or otherwise create binaries that are incompatible with regular binaries. The only additional requirement of ASAN-instrumented objects is that `libasan` is linked in the resulting executable (and is not overridden by any other library that provides `malloc` and friends).

It is perfectly possible and explicitly allowed to link ASAN-instrumented and regular objects together (it is in the [FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#faq)).

Note this has little to do with ODR. ODR is a requirement for source programs, not for compiled programs. Some compiler options, when used incorrectly, may lead to linker errors/runtime errors/inconsistencies similar to those caused by ODR violations. But they are not the same thing.